# How to log in users without credentials?

Tags: 7, users

We need to integrate a CRM into our Drupal site. Storing users in native database is forbidden, so we won't store users in our Drupal database, we will use CRM for that.

But we still need to be able to login/register users from drupal standard login/register forms. On a backend we need to login/register user programmatically so user would think he's logging in/registering on a site, instead he logs in/registers in CRM (which is a third party application).

Comment: When you say storing users in Drupal is forbidden, what are the limits here?  Can there be no user record at all in Drupal (very hard and very unusual) or is just certain information banned and you need to make sure the CRM is the system of record at all times (the typical use case)?  If it is the first you aren't going to be able to get one answer because you have a complex task with multiple challenges to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
global $user;
$user = user_load($uid);
```

Where the $uid is the User ID of the user you want to log in.

Note that this potentially opens you up to major security issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But we won't store users in our drupal database, we will use CRM for that, which is a third party application

Comment: Then you are looking to integrate Drupal into your site, not your site into Drupal. To be honest, I don't see how it could be done - Drupal requires users to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for requires single sign on kind of functinality which user information and authentication process will be done by third party system which is neither of Drupal and CRM, now this third party could be SAML or anything else. Drupal has [SAML integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplesamlphp_auth), the same you might need to implement at your CRM level.

[Know how SAML works](https://developers.onelogin.com/saml)